# MySQL gives Commands out of sync error when using MySQL C driver

Tags: sql, mysql, c

I'm trying to interact with my MySQL database using It's C driver, and I am having issues executing a query on the database.

I have this C function here:

```c
int data_login(char * username, char * password)
{
    MYSQL *dbconn;
    MYSQL_STMT *dbstmt;
    MYSQL_BIND dbbind[2];
    MYSQL_RES *dbres;
    int number_of_rows;
    int result = -8;

    dbconn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if(dbconn == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if(mysql_real_connect(dbconn, dbhostname, dbusername, dbpassword, dbdatabase, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -2;
    }

    dbstmt = mysql_stmt_init(dbconn);

    if(dbstmt == NULL)
    {
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -3;
    }

    char * query = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    if(mysql_stmt_prepare(dbstmt, query, strlen(query)) != 0)
    {
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -4;
    }

    memset(dbbind, 0, sizeof(dbbind));

    dbbind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    dbbind[0].buffer = username;
    dbbind[0].buffer_length = strlen(username);

    dbbind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    dbbind[1].buffer = password;
    dbbind[1].buffer_length = strlen(password);

    if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(dbstmt, dbbind) != 0)
    {
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -5;
    }

    if(mysql_stmt_execute(dbstmt) != 0)
    {
        mysql_stmt_close(dbstmt);
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -6;
    }

    dbres = mysql_store_result(dbconn);

    if(dbres == NULL)
    {
        sendf(stderr, LOG_ERROR, "mysql_store_result() failed: %s (Error code: %d)\n", mysql_error(dbconn), mysql_errno(dbconn));
        mysql_stmt_close(dbstmt);
        mysql_close(dbconn);
        return -7;
    }

    number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows(dbres);
    sendf(stdout, LOG_DEBUG, "%d\n", number_of_rows);

    if(number_of_rows == 0)
    {
        result = -9;
    }
    else if(number_of_rows == 1)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        result = -10;
    }

    mysql_free_result(dbres);
    mysql_stmt_close(dbstmt);
    mysql_close(dbconn);

    return result;
}
```

I basically want this function to search for `username` in the `accounts` table (all usernames are unique), and then compare the password hash with the one in the found entry. If it matches, return `0`, and if not, return `-9`.

For some reason though, when calling this function, I get:

```
[ERROR]: mysql_store_result() failed: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now (Error code: 2014)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?